# \n in variable in heredoc

Tags: bash, variables, escaping, heredoc

Is there any way to for a Bash heredoc to interpret '\n\' in a heredoc?

I have an iteratively built string in a loop, something like

```
for i in word1 word2 word3
do
        TMP_VAR=$i
        ret="$ret\n$TMP_VAR"
done
```

and then I want to use the created string in a heredoc:

```
cat <<EOF > myfile
HEADER
==
$ret
==
TRAILER
EOF
```

however I would like to interpret the "\n" character as newline, so that the output is

```
HEADER
==
word1
word2
word3
==
TRAILER
```

instead of

```
HEADER
==
\nword1\nword2\nword3
==
TRAILER
```

Is it possible? Or should I perhaps build my initial string somehow otherwise?

Comment: I'm not sure what the value of having an _encoded_ newline in a heredoc would be, and I don't think it's directly possible, but it isn't really a dupe. AFAICT nobody has asked specifically for a heredoc newline before.

Comment: If there is a specific character that you can be sure won't ever appear in your heredoc, e.g. `|`, you can substitute `cat <<EOF > myfile` with `tr '|' '\n' <<EOF > myfile`, then use that character as a separator in building your strings... It's not an ideal solution, as `tr` introduces a little bit of extra compute time by having to scan every character, but it should be good enough for most cases...

Comment: The accepted answer suggests that this was a dupe, after all.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In bash you can use `$'\n'` to add a newline to a string:

```
ret="$ret"$'\n'"$TMP_VAR"
```

You can also use `+=` to append to a string:

```
ret+=$'\n'"$TMP_VAR"
```

Answer (score 11):

As others (and other answers to other questions) have said, you can put encoded characters into a string for the shell to interpret.

```
x=$'\n' # newline
printf -v x '\n' # newline
```

That said, I don't believe there is any way to directly put an encoded newline into a *heredoc*.

```
cat <<EOF
\n
EOF
```

just outputs a literal `\n`

```
cat <<$'EOF'
…
EOF
```

is nothing special, nor is `<<'EOF'`

The best you can do is to preencode the newline, and include the expansion in the heredoc:

```
nl=$'\n'
cat <<EOF
foo bar $nl baz
EOF
```

outputs

```
foo bar
 baz
```

Answer (score 8):

Change:

```
==
$ret
==
```

to:

```
==
$(echo -e $ret)
==
```

Answer (score 6):

The best solution is to build your variable with actual newlines, instead of inserting character sequences which need to be replaced with newlines.

I find the following function sufficiently useful that I put it in my bash startup file; for you simple case, it would work perfectly:

```
lines() { printf %s\\n "$@"; }
```

With that, you could write:

```
ret=$(lines word1 word2 word3)
```

instead of the loop you use. Then you can insert `$ret` into the heredoc and it will work as expected. [See note 1]

However, if for whatever reason you really want to construct your string with escape sequences instead of actual characters, you can do the expansion using an extended feature in the bash `printf` built-in, the `%b` format code. `%b` does *almost* the same escape conversions, but there are a couple of differences. See `help printf` for details. Using that you could do the following:

```
$ ret="word1\nword2\nword3"
$ cat <<EOF > tmp
> HEADER
> ==
> $(printf "%b" "$ret")
> ==
> TRAILER
> EOF
$ cat tmp
HEADER
==
word1
word2
word3
==
TRAILER
```

#### Notes

1. There is a subtlety in the use of the `lines` function. `printf` keeps repeating its format string until it absorbs all of its arguments, so that the format `%s\\n` puts a newline after *every* argument, including the last one. For most use cases, that's exactly what you want; most of my uses of lines have to do with feeding the result into a utility which expects lines of inputs.

   But in the case of `ret=$(lines word1 word2 word3)`, I didn't really want the trailing newline, since my plan is to insert `$ret` on a line by itself in the here doc. Fortunately, command substitution (`$(...)`) always deletes trailing newlines from the output of the command, so the value of `ret` after the assignment has newlines *between* the arguments, but not at the end. (This feature is occasionally annoying but more often it is exactly what you wanted, so it goes unnoticed.)

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I forgot I can use command substitution! And BTW you can also use "echo -e" with the same efect as printf "%b".

Comment: @KamilRoman: Actually, you'd need `echo -en` but it's a minor point. `printf` is a lot more flexible. (Particularly the format auto-repeat feature.) But neither `echo -e` nor `printf %b` are standard, so neither of them are portable.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk '{print}'` solves the problem for me.

```sh
cat << EOF |
line1
line2
line3
EOF
awk '{print}' > outputfile
# outputfile contents
cat outputfile
line1
line2
line3
```