# How to expand env var in ANSI C-like string and use literal newline?

Tags: bash, stdin, heredoc, herestring

I am using herestring to pass a string (two input values with newlines) as standard input to an installer executable.
For example, executing an installer with two inputs `/var/tmp` and `yes`

```
#!/bin/bash
# run_installer.sh

./installer <<< $'/var/tmp\nyes\n'
```

But, I need to parameterize the inputs.

e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
# run_installer.sh
export INPUT1="$1"
export INPUT2="$2"

# does not work, it evaluates literally to: ./installer ${INPUT1} ${INPUT2}
./installer <<< $'${INPUT1}\n${INPUT2}\n'
```

So that I can execute it like so:

```
./run_installer /var/tmp yes
```

The question that was marked as a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28090477/n-in-variable-in-heredoc) does not answer this question. It is similar in concept, but different enough to warrant it's own question.

Comment: pls explain downvote

Comment: Shell expansion happens once. You can use a command `< <(printf "$1\n$2\n")`

Comment: This has nothing whatsoever to do with herestrings; it's a question about how to expand variables in `$''`, which isn't herestring-specific syntax. You'd have the exact same issue with, f/e, `var=$'${INPUT1}\n${INPUT2}\n'`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy well I don't know the canonical name for `$''` in bash, what is a better name for the question?

Comment: `$''` syntax is also known as [ANSI C-like strings](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting#ansi_c_like_strings), though that's admittedly quite a mouthful. Same thing happens with just regular single quotes, though; this could *almost* be generalized to [How do I use variables in single quoted strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21192420/how-do-i-use-variables-in-single-quoted-strings), which does cover the necessary details (re: being able to switch between quoting types in a single string).

Comment: @KamilCuk, better `< <(printf '%s\n' "$1" "$2")`, which won't try to treat values inside the variables as if they were part of the format string (with backslashes, `%` signs, etc non-literal).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
./installer <<< "${INPUT1}"$'\n'"${INPUT2}"$'\n'
```

or:

```
EOL=$'\n'
./installer <<< "${INPUT1}${EOL}${INPUT2}${EOL}"
```

Anyway, the last EOL ist not needed, because it is inserted automatically.

Comment: You beat me to it, lol

Comment: This does not work, the installer is passed only one input, `'/var/tmp\nyes\n'`, the newlines are the escaped char, not the literal newline

Comment: I tested it with `cat - <<< "${INPUT1}${EOL}${INPUT2}${EOL}"` and the result is `in1\nin2\n\n` (INPUT1/2 are set to `in1` and `in2`)

Comment: @JamesWierzba This certainly does work exactly as-given; see https://ideone.com/RBicmM

Comment: @C.Duffy: shell is bash.

Comment: @Wiimm, We both agree on that, don't we?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy and Wimm, it was my mistake. I mistakenly used double quotes for both EOL var and the herestring, It does work

Comment: @C.Duffy We do!